# Why is my git smudge filter slow?

Tags: git

I have the following filters in git (I've expanded them onto lines for a bit more readability):

```
git config --global filter.lastcommit.smudge 
'IFS=""; 
lastcommit=`git log -1 --format="%H" -- %f`; 
filename=$(basename %f); 
while read -r; 
do 
    line="${REPLY//\$Revision\$/\$Revision: $lastcommit\$}";
    line="${line//\$RCSfile\$/\$RCSfile: $filename\$}"; 
    echo $line; 
done'

git config --global filter.dater.smudge 
'IFS=""; myDate=`git log --pretty=format:"%cI" -1 --format="%H" -- %f`; 
while read -r; 
    do line="${REPLY//\$Date\$/\$Date: $myDate\$}"; 
    echo $line; 
done'
```

When I checkout a branch, the filters are run on approximately ~260+ files within the three directories with a .gitattributes file, but it can take up to a few seconds to perform filtering on each one:

```
Checking out files: 100% (6659/6659), done.
Branch ABC set up to track remote branch ABC from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'ABC'

real    4m42.334s
user    4m15.607s
sys 0m29.788s
```

Is there a way to improve the performance?

**SOLUTION**: I switched to using sed after reading @torek answer. Filters are now:

```
git config --global filter.lastcommit.smudge 
'lastcommit=`git log -1 --format="%H" -- %f`; 
filename=$(basename %f); 
sed -e "s/\\\$Revision\\\$/\$Revision: $lastcommit\$/" 
    -e "s/\\\$RCSfile\\\$/\$RCSfile: $filename\$/";'

git config --global filter.dater.smudge 
'myDate=`git log --pretty=format:"%cI" -1 -- %f`; 
sed -e "s/\\\$Date\\\$/\$Date: $myDate\$/";'
```

And the gains are very impressive:

```
~/panos > time git checkout ABC
Checking out files: 100% (6659/6659), done.
Branch ABC set up to track remote branch ABC from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'ABC'

real    0m12.956s
user    0m10.417s
sys    0m2.452s
```

I was under the impression that a fork to sed would have been more costly than using pure bash. Turns out sed is much more efficient for text replacement. I learned something today.

Comment: I found this commentary on bash `read` speeds above section 7.2.2.1 - http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch07_02.htm#KSH-CH-7-SECT-2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I've never used clean and smudge filters but the concept seems simple enough.

You're doing the smudge operation entirely in `bash` code, using `read -r`.  This is highly inefficient (for good reasons that don't apply to your case) and is likely the source of all the slowness.  Using `sed` instead should speed things up enormously.

The `-e s/regexp/replacement/` arguments to `sed` are basically the same as the substitutions here (you need only protect the final `$` from regexp matching) so it should be quite straightforward to switch.

Comment: Even using sed, it takes around 0.4s per `git log` which, if you've got some 250 files to modify makes an extra almost **2 minutes** of checkout time because the operations all seem to happen in serial. This is simply not acceptable for most users.

Unless there's some trick to getting the `git log` data faster or the smudge filters to happen in parallel, I think the only way to get reasonable performance is to not use smudge filters at all, but to have a separate post-processing of the files that can happen in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Note: beware of accessing `%f` file content directly in your (smudge/clean) script.

See [commit 52db4b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52db4b0467f157230d2746f10435d070ad859bae) (03 Aug 2016) by [Joey Hess (`joeyh`)](https://github.com/joeyh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 104985c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/104985c59eb5f318daf6732af9a2b7a9f63d0857), 08 Aug 2016)</sup>

The [`.gitattributes` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/104985c59eb5f318daf6732af9a2b7a9f63d0857/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L374-L384) now (Git 2.10, Q3 2016) includes:

```
[filter "p4"]
    clean = git-p4-filter --clean %f
    smudge = git-p4-filter --smudge %f
```

> Note that "`%f`" is the name of the path that is being worked on.
>   Depending on the version that is being filtered, the corresponding file on disk may not exist, or may have different contents.
>   **So, smudge and clean commands should not try to access the file on disk, but only act as filters on the content provided to them on standard input**.